# Put Javascript in Wordpress Navigation Menu?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu, navigation, chat

Is there a way to put javascript in the URL portion of a Wordpress menu item? I have a live chat function on my site, and I am supposed to put this code onto the site to make a link to open the live chat ([as suggested here](https://www.olark.com/customer/portal/articles/317635)).

```
<!-- BEGIN OLARK CHAT LINK -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="olark('api.box.expand')">
    Click here to chat!
</a>
<!-- END OLARK CHAT LINK -->
```

The client wants the link in the utility nav bar, which was created used a Wordpress menu in the Wordpress dashboard. But when I copy and paste `javascript:void(0);" onclick="olark('api.box.expand')` into the URL box in the Wordpress dashboard, it just disappears and the link remains inactive.

Any ideas on how to achieve this without a plugin?

Comment: Where do you have declared the function `olark()`?

Comment: Olark handles all of the functions. The chat function is working on the site from a different link. I just need to know how to get the link working in the nav menu.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. In case anyone else is looking for the same thing, here's the code that worked for me.

```
// Live Chat Utility Link
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'live_chat_utility_link', 10, 2 );
function live_chat_utility_link ( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'utility' ) {
        $items .= '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="olark(\'api.box.expand\')" class="livechat">Live Chat</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: How you target specific menu item with this code? I want to add this code to specific menu item:

gtag('event', 'Click to Call', {
  'event_category': 'Phone Call Tracking',
  'event_label': '0884344644',
  'value': 0
});